# ClassNotFoundException while running the OTC framework test project

Tags: java, otcconverter, otcframework

`enter code here`ClassNotFoundExcpetion while trying to map a source to a target object using an OTC framework

Steps To reproduce:

1. Created pojo class for ndc schema version 18.1(target) and 21.3(source).
2. Copied the jars files into otc-home->lib folder.
3. Started otceditor.jar file inside otc folder.
4. Created a mapping file and the otc editor generates entryClassName: <> with given source and target package name.
5. While testing the generated otcs file using the test project provided in otc framework, an error was returned in  OtcExecutor, as
   "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AirShopping.IATAAirShoppingRQ__AirShoppingRQ"

Please help me to resolve the issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the "/tmd" and "/target" folders in ${OTC_HOME} and run again. Some files generated during the previous compilation must be there.

Comment: It worked thanks to your assistance.